# Plotting categorial groupings in bokeh with geopandas not working? (Problem with CategoricalColorMapper)

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, geopandas

I'm having problems plotting groupings of countries on a world map using Bokeh in combination with the geopandas package. What I want to do is colour each country in a group with a certain colour on the map. The groupings are saved in the dataframe "dataset", which is merged with the geopandas geographical info, converted to json and fed to the mapping functions. (Code below.)

The interesting thing is that no error is generated, Bokeh even reports that "BokehJS 1.4.0 successfully loaded", but no chart is shown.

I am quite convinced that the problem is with my implementation of the CategoricalColorMapper. This is evident since if I change the color mapper to to linear color mapper, the code works perfectly. 
This code does not work:

```
from bokeh.palettes import viridis
from bokeh.models import FactorRange
dataset = gdf.merge(dataset, left_on = 'country', right_on = 'location', how = 'left')
#gdf is geopandas geo info dataframe

#Read data to json
dataset_json = json.loads(dataset.to_json())

#Convert to str like object
dataset_json_data = json.dumps(dataset_json)

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = dataset_json_data)

catValues=list(dataset["val"].dropna().unique().astype("str"))

palette=viridis(len(catValues))

print("Palette len:", len(palette))
print("Factors:", len(catValues))

print(dataset)

color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(palette = palette , factors=catValues)

#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = title_string, plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource, fill_color = {'field' :'val', 'transform' : color_mapper})

#Display figure inline in Jupyter Notebook.
output_notebook()

#Display figure.
show(p)
```

Calling the function prints the following, but non map is shown. The number of colors and categories seems fine to me?

Palette len: 118

Factors: 118

BokehJS 1.4.0 successfully loaded.

Replacing only the color mapper works perfectly. This code works:

```
def plot_map(dataset, title_string = ""):
dataset = gdf.merge(dataset, left_on = 'country', right_on = 'location', how = 'left')

#Read data to json
dataset_json = json.loads(dataset.to_json())

#Convert to str like object
dataset_json_data = json.dumps(dataset_json)

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = dataset_json_data)

#Define a sequential multi-hue color palette.
palette = brewer['OrRd'][7]

#Reverse color order so that dark blue is highest obesity.
palette = palette[::-1]

#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = dataset.val.min(), high = dataset.val.max())

#Define custom tick labels for color bar.
#tick_labels = {'0': '0', '1': '1', '2':'2', '3':'3', '4':'4', '5':'5', '6':'6','7':'7'}

#Create color bar. 
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=7,width = 500, height = 20,
border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)

#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = title_string, plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource, fill_color = {'field' :'val', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)

#Specify figure layout.
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

#Display figure inline in Jupyter Notebook.
output_notebook()

#Display figure.
show(p)
```

Comment: It's certainly also possible there is just a bug. But to investigate would require a complete minimal script (including any real or synthetic data that's necessary) that could actually be executed.